# Error in SSIS script component

Tags: ssis

I have a problem while executing a SSIS script component. To be honest I am learning SSIS and for the script component, I am going thru [The Script Component as a Transformation](http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Script-Component-as-a-Transformation.aspx) Article. I have so far done whatever has been stated there . But while I am trying to execute the package, I am encountering the below error

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [16]]: The script component is configured to pre-compile the script, but binary code is not found. Please visit the IDE in Script Component Editor by clicking Design Script button to cause binary code to be generated.
Error at Data Flow Task [DTS.Pipeline]: "component "Script Component" (16)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [DTS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

A bit of googling reveals the following [Package Validation Error](http://www.windows-tech.info/15/b2dffa1693bf9f99.php) . So after going thru that , I understood what is the cause of the problem but how to rectify that , I don't know. Moreover, debugging is not possible.

Please help me.

EDIT

At last I found out that the Precompiled Option should be set to FALSE. Default is TRUE. It solved the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically get this error when some portion of your script is no longer functioning correctly. This is often due to a dependency in the script that is no longer valid. Why can't you debug the package? If this is not your package then you're going to have to find the person who wrote it and have them fix the errors.

Comment: But the debugging option is not there

Comment: Even I tried with a simple example as MsgBox("hello") . Then also I got the same error. As I mentioned that I myself is learning so I cannot figure out why? Is there any setting that I need to do?

Comment: The debugging options is not there? What does that mean? Simply press F5 within Visual Studio to start running the package in Debug mode.

Comment: Thanks you sir. I found out the solution. Precompiled Option should be set to FALSE . Dafault it is True. 
And regarding debugging, I have notified all those what your are saying, but by some reason even after pressing F5, it is not working.
But thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sometime is enough to rebuild the task, just edit it and build in vsta.

Comment: or rebuild the SSIS project as a whole

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into this issue and discovered is was because our code was too modern. The person who wrote the script used some newer code candy like:

somestring = $"{somevariable}-{Someothervariable}"

SomeFunctionWithOutParameter(out bool myResult)

It looked fine in the VS2017 editor on my colleague's machines but for some reason when I edited the script it was being pulled up in VS2015 (SSIS was being edited in VS2017) and the code was flagged.

After reverting the code to older style using String.Format() and pre-declaring the out variable the script was able to compile and run.

My guess is that whatever is compiling the script task code is not using the latest and greatest c# compiler.